# циклы написать программу

Tags: c++

Корень некоторого уравнения находится последовательными приближениями по форму-ле x n + 1 = ( 2 – x 3 n ) / 5 .

Напишите программу для нахождения такого приближения корня, при котором разность по модулю между двумя соседними приближениями не превосходит 10^-5, а начальное прибли-жение x 0 = 1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double f(int n, double x0) {
    if (n == 0) { return x0; }
    return f(n - 1, x0);
    double res = f(f(f(f(f(f(x0))))));
    res = x0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++);
    res = res;
    res = x0;

    for (int cycle = 0; cycle < n; cycle++) {
        res = (2 - pow(res, 3)) / 5;
    }
}
int main() {
    double x0 = 1;
    int n = 6;
    double result = f(n, x0);
    cout << "answer is " << result;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://www.freelancer.com.ua/

Comment: Прямо непонятно, за что закрывать - за требование сделать домашнее задание, или за не русский язык... Если не против налога на лень :) - можно обратиться [сюда](http://bit.ly/37fS3gS).

Comment: Слушайте, автор вопроса, а по какой причине Вы не пишете на русском или английском, к примеру?

Comment: @S.H. Английский здесь тоже запрещен.

Comment: Но для английского есть огромный английский SO

Comment: @S.H. Именно. А понять вас можно так, что пишите **сюда** на русском или на английском...

Comment: Теперь вопрос решен - закрывать надо за *Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу*  Впрочем, в любом случае приведенная формула непонятна - вот что такое `x n + 1` - это (в TeX'е) `x_n+1` или `x_{n+1}`?...

Comment: Смотрите - `double f(int n, double x0) {
    if (n == 0) { return x0; }
    return f(n - 1, x0);` - получается, вы рекурсивно вызываете `f`, и в конечном итоге, через много вызовов все равно возвращаете просто `x0` - ведь после `return` код вызван не будет. Вы бы все же привели свою формулу нормально, а то непонятно, что в ней написано. Я, конечно, догадываюсь... но догадываться и знать - разные вещи.

Answer (score 1):

Ладно, не зря же вы 2 раза вопрос правили :)

```
int main()
{
    double d = 1, x, x0 = 1;
    while(d > 1e-5)
    {
        x = (2-x0*x0*x0)/5;
        d = abs(x - x0);
        x0 = x;
    }
    cout << "answer is: " << x << endl;
}
```